# Target iframe Raphael Js

Tags: text, href, javascript, target, raphael

Ive been trying to target iframe using Raphael JS

heres some sample code

var c = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
c.attr({href: "http://google.com/", target: "top"});
v

var t = paper.text(250, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!");
t.attr({href: "http://google.com/", target: "_blank"});

Also..cant get href to work with text
ar t = paper.text(50, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!");
t.attr({href: "http://google.com/", target: "_blank"});

Answer (score 1):

After spending a little time to think it out

c.node.onclick = function load2 (iframe1URL, iframe2URL) {
     parent.iframe1.location.href='page1.htm'
    parent.iframe2.location.href='page2.htm'